# Error in Parallel.ForEach - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach

I have a strange problem that I am unable to debug.  Here's a delegate that parses information:

```
Action<XElement, String> ParseXMLInfo = (s, t) =>
{
    using (var Ctx = new Entities())
    {
        var Records = s.Elements("record");
        Parallel.ForEach(
            ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, Records.Count()),
            u =>
            {
                var el = Records.ElementAt(u);
                try
                {
                    var NTR = new tbl_UserInfo();
                    NTR.first_name = el.Element("first_name").Value;
                    NTR.last_name = el.Element("last_name").Value;
                    Ctx.AddTotbl_UserInfo(NTR);
                }
                catch (Exception excp)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now + " " + excp.Message);
                }
            }
        );
        Ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
};
```

The delegate itself is called twice, as follows:

```
Parallel.Invoke(
    () =>
    {
        var XMLDoc_MaleInfo = XElement.Load("MaleNames.xml");
        Console.WriteLine("Fetching records from MaleNames.xml; starting at " + System.DateTime.Now);
        ParseXMLInfo(XMLDoc_MaleInfo, "male");
    },
    () =>
    {
        var XMLDoc_FemaleInfo = XElement.Load("FemaleNames.xml");
        Console.WriteLine("Fetching records from FemaleNames.xml; starting at " + System.DateTime.Now);
        ParseXMLInfo(XMLDoc_MaleInfo, "female");
    }
);
```

Everything appears to run correctly.  In particular, the `Parallel.ForEach` portion of the delegate runs without any error.  But then, the code breaks at the line `Ctx.SaveChanges ()`, with the message

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

But when I hover over `Ctx` (in this broken state), `Ctx` is not shown to be `null`.

Can someone please tell me what is going on?

Comment: Can you post your `Entities` class? I suspect it's not threadsafe. And you're writing to it from multiple threads.

Comment: @CodeInChaos The Entities class was generated by .NET when I added an ADO.NET Entity Data Model.  I did not modify the code that was generated for it by the system itself.  If you really want, I can post the entire file, but it is quite long.

Comment: @CodeInChaos You are probably on to something.  When I comment out the "try" and "catch" lines, I get the following error for AttTotbl_UserInfo:  "The type Test.tbl_UserInfo has been mapped more than once."

Answer (score 0):

Think it should be:

```
ParallelEnumerable.Range (0, Records.Count()-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after much scanning through MSDN documentation, I appear to have come up with at least one solution for now.  Here is the re-factored code.

```
Action<XElement, String> ParseXMLInfo = (s, t) => {
            var Records = s.Elements ("record");
            Parallel.ForEach (
                ParallelEnumerable.Range (0, Records.Count ()),
                () => new Testing_And_Benchmarking_Entities (),
                (u, L, v) => {
                    var el = Records.ElementAt (u);
                    var NTR = new tbl_UserInfo ();
                    NTR.first_name = el.Element ("first_name").Value;
                    NTR.last_name = el.Element ("last_name").Value;
                    v.AddTotbl_UserInfo (NTR);
                    return v;
                },
                (v) => v.SaveChanges ()
            );
        };
        Parallel.Invoke (
            () => {
                var XMLDoc_MaleInfo = XElement.Load ("MaleNames.xml");
                Console.WriteLine ("Fetching records from MaleNames.xml; starting at " + System.DateTime.Now);
                ParseXMLInfo (XMLDoc_MaleInfo, "male");
            },
            () => {
                var XMLDoc_FemaleInfo = XElement.Load ("FemaleNames.xml");
                Console.WriteLine ("Fetching records from MaleNames.xml; starting at " + System.DateTime.Now);
                ParseXMLInfo (XMLDoc_FemaleInfo, "female");
            }
        );
```

I had to use a different overloaded signature of Parallel.ForEach.  In this overload, the equivalent to the Ctx variable in the previous example ("v" in this example, please pardon the cryptic variable names) is not shared.  So the error is avoided.

I would still appreciate a comment from someone knowledgeable as to whether my solution is the only one, or whether there is a better, more idiomatic C# solution.